# REST API: user-agent-based client (app) authorization

Tags: javascript, api, rest, authentication, flask

I have two separate web apps:

- database API
- and basic web-client (Flask) with some JS-code (Knockout.js) for interactive
  features like filtering products 'on-the-fly', cart, etc.

To implement interactive answers through API I use JavaScript requests running in a user's browser. I want to control access to API and give it only to authorized web-apps, for example, my own client JS-code.

I read about HMAC and Oauth. The key point: the server and the client share the same secret which is used to generate a HMAC, for example.

But how should I generate a HMAC inside a user's browser using a secret and not exposing the secret to others? As I understand, if my JS-code has access to a secret, than anybody on the internet has that access, right?

Comment: you can use https to secure the datas

Comment: Okay, using HTTPS I secure communication between a client and a server. But the client still has to send some credentials. And my client is a JS-code which is accessible to everybody. So what's is accessible by my client app is accessible by everyone, right?

Comment: yes right, but you can use a private key per client, use checksum for data integrity, etc.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

JavaScript applications are what are called [*'public clients'*](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1) in OAuth 2.0. It basically means they cannot keep secrets and therefore you **cannot** do client (application) authorization.

So, if you are using a JavaScript application to talk to your API, you'll need to do user authentication and give users access to your API. Or switch to a server side application to access your API.

Comment: Is there any way to restrict access to js-file? I saw such thing on the web when I had been discovering one web app, from the <head> tag I got a link to something like `catalog.js` which is accessible by the website itself but when you try to access the link -- it's 0-length content file.

Comment: Not sure what happened there, but if the browser can get the file, so should you using the same authentication as the browser is using. Open up the F12 developer tools and in the Network tab you can see what request the browser is making and the response the server is sending.