# Secure REST API + frontend web-app without user authentication

Tags: javascript, rest, authentication, flask, frontend

I have a database with API written in Python (Flask). I want to build a frontend which makes requests to API and display data. But I want to control the access to the API.

I couldn't implement authorization because my web app is a [public client](https://www.rfc-editor.org/rfc/rfc6749#section-2.1) type (according to Oauth RFC) -- so there is no way to store credentials securely to authenticate the app. And I don't need user authentication (the web app is a simple catalog with interactive filters and cart).

So I need somehow to protect JS-code (uglifying/obfuscating is not enough, because I have ajax requests with URIs) or rebuild the whole web app in some way to hide ajax requests and secure the API.

Does anybody has any ideas and hints how is it possible to secure API + frontend web-app without user authentication?

It should be trivial because there're a lot of products catalogs which work in interactive manner like [tesco](http://www.tesco.com/direct/technology-gaming/binoculars-telescopes/cat3376483.cat?pageViewType=grid&sortBy=1&catId=4294960143+40679&lastFilter=Price%7C%25A310+to+%C2%A320) and its filtering mechanism. But I don't understand how.

Could you give a hint?

---

The previous question [REST API: user-agent-based client (app) authorization](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/34995186/rest-api-user-agent-based-client-app-authorization/34996406#34996406)

Comment: Similar question with lots of good hints: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/11923208/how-to-secure-web-service-without-login